# jQuery Mobile listview thumbnail image alignment

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Hi I added a list view with thumbnail

using

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-theme="a" data-dividertheme="d">
<li><a href="image.php?imgid=2">  
    <img src="../images/comma.png" class="ui-li-thumb" />  
    <h3 class="ui-li-heading">Colleeeeeeeeeeeeege</h3>  
    <p class="ui-li-desc">by Scott Hill</p></a></li> 
</ul>
```

and getting image but **its not at center how to fit it in thumbnail area**

see image here

[image]

help is really appreciated

Comment: Have you try to add `vertical-align: middle` style to the `img` element?

Comment: @StanleyW. yes tried this but no change appears

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  I added the below event to sets the needed top padding.

```
$("img[class='ui-li-thumb']").load(function() {
    $(this).css('padding-top',((80-this.height)/2));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed the height of each of the lists in the list-view then you can give margin-top for the img tag and adjust so that it comes to the center

```
<style>
.listex{
height:50px;
}
 .ui-li-thumb{
   margin-top:10px;
 }
</style>
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-theme="a" data-dividertheme="d">
   <li class="listex"><a href="image.php?imgid=2">  
       <img src="../images/comma.png" class="ui-li-thumb" />  
       <h3 class="ui-li-heading">Colleeeeeeeeeeeeege</h3>  
       <p class="ui-li-desc">by Scott Hill</p></a>
   </li> 
</ul>
```

You should set the values of height and margin-top accordingly.

Comment: @Klra its fine if every image having the same problem but some image heights are fit to row then into this case it goes down using margin-top:10px;

Comment: @RohanPatil ok. But are all the images of the same dimensions??